# Specific folders of postman collection runs from tool successfully but throws a 401 error while running from newman tool with --folder option

Tags: collections, automation, directory, postman, newman

The postman collection file has the environment settings, globals and data files which are configured
and runs successfully from postman

From newman

```
newman run -e ..\..\Source\ABCDEF\test\Automation\API_Webservices\Environment\GHIJ_QA.postman_environment.json -g ..\..\Source\LMNOPQRSTUV\test\Automation\API_Webservices\Globals\A12345_4568.postman_globals.json --folder Folder1 -d ..\..\Source\LMNOPQRSTUV\test\Automation\API_Webservices\TestData\test.json ..\..\Source\LMNOPQRSTUV\test\Automation\API_Webservices\Collections\MicroServices\A12345_4568\MicroServices.postman_collection.json -r htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export ..\..\Source\LMNOPQRSTUV\test\Automation\API_Webservices\Output\Output_HTMLReport.html

expected response to have status code 200 but got 401
RESPONSE INFORMATION
Response Code:401 - Unauthorized
```

The folder level services implemented would need to be run either as single folder or multiple folders in sequence to check simple and advanced flows.

Currently this is not working from newman CLI but from tool only.
**Should the collectionvariables used inside the script be made global to work in newman?
Is that a possible issue please shed some light**

Comment: It looks like something is working but some of the endpoints are unauthorised (401) - How are you authenticating those requests. Do you use the Auth helpers to create tokens for your requests?

Comment: yes i use the auth helpers to create the tokens. the endpoints all sit in same env either QA or Dev or Staging. so ideally the syntax given by newman should support .